# What is Multiservice IP Network

Tags: internet

I read in different place on the internet, on research papers and books the term "Multiservice IP Network" or "Multiservice Network" or even "Multiservice Traffic".

What is the meaning of these different expressions, especially the first ones ?

Comment: Could you provide a context for those terms? Where did you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiservice networks have mixture of different traffic types (e.g. various data, VoIP, video, etc.) converged on the same network, and the network can properly support the various applications requiring the disparate traffic. This typically requires a very good set of QoS policies that are implemented consistently across the entire network. The first two terms you list are interchangeable, while the last term describes the diversity of network traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the fats answer Ron, any example of Multiservice Networks? are our nowadays networks, like internet just one of them ?

Comment: Many company networks are multiservice networks. The networks contains a mixture of different traffic, such as traditional data, instrumentation (e.g., IoT), VoIP, one-way, two-way, and/or conference video, etc. While the Internet carries a wide variety of traffic types, there is no QoS or SLAs (net neutrality) across the ISPs which the traffic must traverse. A true multiservice network would provide comprehensive QoS policies with SLAs. The Internet is really hit-or-miss, and what works well at a particular day and time may not work at all on a different day or time.